# Pull the max lengh substring sorted in alphabetical order using ASCII

Tags: python, string, substring, ascii

please help me to solve this. I am a beginner and this exercise drives me crazy as I tried slicing and now ASCII, which seems easier for me?
I have only managed to pull the char's ord values if it is greater than previous char in the string. How to get maximally sorted substring from the array of letters or at least their ord values? (the code should pull: 'fruw' as it maximally sorted)

```
s = 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl'
s2 = []
print s
for char in range(0, len(s)):
        if ord(s[char]) >= ord(s[char-1]):
            s2.append(str(ord(s[char])))
print s2
```

Am I thinking in the right way or which amendments should I make? thanks

Comment: I see you are using s[char-1] ... with a for loop starting char with 0 this results in s[-1] which is the last character; possibly you need to start with index 1?

Comment: You don't need `ord` to lexicographically compare two letters. You can just compare them with `<`.

Comment: @Joel They already did, it's "fruw".

Comment: Consider this. Iterating through the characters as you are, at each character, one of two things happens: (a) `s[i] >= s[i-1]` and the current candidate string length increments; (b) `s[i] < s[i-1]` and a new candidate string begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does the same thing, and it is a lot simpler to read and understand what it does for anybody who has to work with your code (including yourself in the future).

```
def find_lss(s):
    if not s:
        return s # empty s or None
    solutions = []
    current = None
    for char in s:
        if current is None or current[-1] > char:
            if current is not None: solutions.append(current)
            current = char
        else:
            current += char
    solutions.append(current)
    return max(solutions, key=len)
```

Note that there is no need to use `ord()`, because, comparing characters directly works just fine for your problem.

Then you can use it with your example:

```
>>> find_lss('gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl')
'fruw'
```

More importantly, this implementation also works with the classical corner-case, the empty string:

```
>>> find_lss('')
''
```

And it even works with `None`:

```
>>> find_lss(None)
```

(No output, and no error; I.e., the function returned `None`.)

Comment: Yes, this solution is the best so far. Other solutions still give out error (e.g. those do not consider that chars can repeat in the substring or if string is a complete alphabet)... thanks for input anyway

Comment: Just asking, Can you tell the error in my code apart from the empty string (which can be taken care of by writing an extra line of code)?

Comment: @BhargavRao Isn't that very serious bug, OP's system may crash due to that. :-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks. It takes a bit of intelligence to do the end limit checking, which I do not possess :( . I learned two things. Firstly, I have to check the last character, secondly the null string. Thanks both of you. :)

Comment: In short: if your function takes strings, make sure it works with all kinds of strings. That is what "corner cases" are. And, due to a sad design decision decades of years ago, many programming languages have one ugly and very nasty wart: the NULL/None/Null/Nil/... value. So in those languages you always also have to think about the case that your variable takes that value, too, if you want to write good code. Normally, by returning the NULL, as done here, or by raising an exception *and documenting it*.

Answer (score 1):

I have minimally tried and changed your code

```
s = 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl'
s2 = ""                                      # a temporary string to hold value
temp = []                                    # added an extra array
print s
if s:
    for char in range(0, len(s)-1):
            if ord(s[char+1]) >= ord(s[char]):   # same as your code
                s2+=s[char]
            else:                                # if some letter is smaller, then add the previously longest str to temp array
                s2+=s[char]
                temp.append(s2)
                s2 = ""
    s2+=s[char+1]                                # As pointed out, the last letter would not have been detected as we loop up to len -1, thus we need to add this
    temp.append(s2)
    print max(temp,key = len)                    # print the longest string
else:
    print s
```

The comments try and explain the changes

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for that string. Forgot to add the last char to the list at the end. 2 lines should fix that

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it your way first using indexing:

```
def solve(s):
    max_g = [] # this will store the final answer
    curr_g = [s[0]] # this list will store the contents of current group, start with first item. 
    for i in xrange(1, len(s)):
        c = s[i]
        # Now if the current character is greater than or equal to
        # last item in curr_g then simply append the current item to
        # curr_g
        # else compare the length of current_group with max_g
        # if it's greater than length of max_g then we have found a
        # new bigger group, so time to update value of max_g
        # and lastly update curr_g to [c]
        if c >= curr_g[-1]:
            curr_g.append(c)
        else:
            if len(curr_g) > len(max_g):
                max_g = curr_g
            curr_g = [c]

    #One last check of the group
    if curr_g and len(curr_g) > len(max_g):
        return ''.join(curr_g)
    else:
        return ''.join(max_g)

s = 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl'
print solve(s)
# fruw
```

---

A better way using generator function and `max`. This will at a time will store only one group in memory:

```
def groups(s):
    it = iter(s)
    group = [next(it)]
    for c in it:
        if c >= group[-1]:
            group.append(c)
        else:
            yield ''.join(group)
            group = [c]
    if group:
        yield ''.join(group)
```

**Usage:**

```
print max(groups(s), key=len)
# fruw
```

---

**Update:**

Of course If you want to handle empty strings then add a simply `if` condition that the top of the function. And as you didn't specify much about what to do with repeated characters(in fact you're using `>=` in your answer as well), but judging by your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985490/pull-the-max-lengh-substring-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-using-ascii/27985840?noredirect=1#comment44366486_27986568) on another answer what you wanted was a simple `>`.

Comment: Question - is there an advantage to creating the list `group` and then joining versus what I did as just having a string and using `+=`?  (obviously the generator is nicer than what I did since it preserves memory)

Comment: @Joel  `+=` is optimized for strings only in certain cases(can vary with various implementations), for example in CPython it works in linear time only if there's one reference to our string. So, it's is recommended to use `str.join` over a list than using `+=`. [Read the 6th point](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: Actually, the example with `groups` is dangerous: it excepts with a ValueError on empty input strings. Just try `max(groups(''), key=len)`.

Comment: And, just tried your solution `solve`, which is even worse; You get an IndexError for the empty string corner case - just try `solve('')`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I guess that is exactly the reason why there are so many bugs and exploits in the world. Learn to write functions that work for all corner cases instead of asking the callers of your function to remember that they have to hedge it with protective code as it explodes in their face otherwise.

Comment: With all due respect and meaning no insult, but I don't think it's funny that someone with more than 100k points on SO does not understand the concept of a [corner case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case): "specifically one that manifests itself when multiple environmental variables or conditions are simultaneously at extreme levels, even though each parameter is within the **specified range for that parameter**."

Answer (score 0):

So we you've got a lot of effort going into tracking which index you're at.  Iterating directly as `for x in y` is much cleaner.  Also, no need to do all of the list syntax for s2.  Just make your s2 a string.

```
s = 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl'
biglist = []
substring = s[0]  #this is going to get the first character
for char in s[1:]:   #loop over remaining characters
    if char > substring[-1]:   #if in order, add to end of string
        substring += char
    else:                     #if out of order, save what we have, start over
        biglist.append(substring)
        substring = char
biglist.append(substring)   #save the last thing

print biglist
    
print max(biglist, key = len)
```

output is

> ['g', 'as', 'gr', 'eru', 'px', 'k', 'g', 'fruw', 'go', 'h', 'fz', 'l']
>
> fruw

Answer (score 0):

You could try `izip_longest()` to create pairs of adjacent characters and compare these in a loop:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def longest_sorted_substring(s):
    longest = tmp = []
    for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s, s[1:]):
        tmp.append(c1)
        if c1 > c2:
            longest = max(tmp, longest, key=len)
            tmp = []
    return ''.join(longest)

>>> for s in 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl', '', 'a', 'ab', 'ba', 'acb', 'abdefgaooooooooozq', '123456780123456789abc0d':
...     print "Longest sorted substring of '{}' is '{}'".format(s, longest_sorted_substring(s))
... 
Longest sorted substring of 'gasgrerupxkgfruwgohfzl' is 'fruw'
Longest sorted substring of '' is ''
Longest sorted substring of 'a' is 'a'
Longest sorted substring of 'ab' is 'ab'
Longest sorted substring of 'ba' is 'a'
Longest sorted substring of 'acb' is 'ac'
Longest sorted substring of 'abdefgaooooooooozq' is 'aoooooooooz'
Longest sorted substring of '123456780123456789abc0d' is '0123456789abc'
```

Note that `izip_longest()` is used because it handles the final character without adding a special case to handle the end of string.